# store every line of input in an array with getline c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, input, getline

I'm using getline to get input and I want to store every line input to an array so that I can recall specific array content for further processing. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
string line;

while (true) {

    getline(cin, line);

    if (line.empty()) {
        break;
    }
    // code

}
```

EDIT/ADD

Does anyone know why I cannot use `cin` before the while loop? When for example I put 
    `cin >> var1;` before the loop it won't go inside the loop at all!

ANSWERING MYSELF

I found [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/51433/) that solves it!

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` is your friend.

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: By the way, do you really want to stop processing input completely on the first blank line? Or just ignore that line? Also, I'd suggest moving the `getline` into the loop condition, so that you read and immediately check it succeeded: `while(std::getline(std::cine, line)) { ... }`.

Comment: Yeah I want to get inputs as long as the user gives, and then with the empty line I signal my program that there are no more inputs, I can't think of a better way other than prompting the user to press enter twice when they've entered their last input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use vector container:

```
 std::vector<std::string> arr;
```

and then:

```
arr.push_back(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `vector<string> vec;`

Better way to read from file would be as below

```
string line;

while (getline(cin, line)) {

if (line.empty()) {
    break;
}
vec.push_back(line);
// code

}
```

once EOF  is reached loop will break...

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answers everyone, I'm just now trying to get the hang of std::vector.
Let's say that after storing the getline input into vec, I want to convert certain strings (vec[0] etc.) to int or double, can that be done within vec or is it mandatory to initialise new variables or vectors? thanks!

Comment: No that cannot be done within vector `stringstream` comes very handy for such conversion..check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/)

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look and let you know ;)

Comment: instead of using stringstream, I thought I'd use
    `int var1=atoi(vec[0]);`
    or
    `int var1=atoi(vec.at[0]);`
but none of them work...Any ideas why?

Comment: Shouldn't that work since I'm converting from a vector of strings to integers?

Comment: @user3374479 made mistake in above comment...`atoi()` takes char * and you are passing string object.. resulting error try `atoi(vec[0].c_str())`... that should work

Comment: It says here to avoid comments like "thanks", but.. 
you da man HadeS!! Have a nice day! ;)